# How do I save an Excel file without getting a format warning when opening, using C# and Excel 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, excel, format, savefiledialog

I'm using Excel 2010.
I'm trying so save my excel file, with this code. 
It does save a .xls file, but when I open the file I get this message:

> The file you are trying to open, 'tre.xls', is in a different format than specified by the file extension. Verify that the file is not corrupted and is from a thrusted source before opening the file. Do you want to open the file now?

If I press `yes`the file opens. But what do I need to get rid of this format-popup?

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using ExcelAddIn1.Classes;
using ExcelAddIn1.Classes.Config;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Application = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


private void Foo(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
    saveFileDialog.Filter = "Execl files (*.xls)|*.xls";
    saveFileDialog.FilterIndex = 0;
    saveFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;
    saveFileDialog.CreatePrompt = true;
    saveFileDialog.FileName = null;
    saveFileDialog.Title = "Save path of the file to be exported";

    if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // Save. 
        // The selected path can be got with saveFileDialog.FileName.ToString()
        Application excelObj = 
            (Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
        Workbook wbook = excelObj.ActiveWorkbook;
        wbook.SaveAs(saveFileDialog.FileName, XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, 
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, false, false, 
            XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        wbook.Close();
    }
}
```

When I save in excel in the normal way I get "Book1.xlsx", that have no problem to open.

============= FINAL SOLUTION ============

```
private void Foo(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
    saveFileDialog.Filter = "Execl files (*.xls)|*.xls";

    saveFileDialog.FilterIndex = 0;
    saveFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;
    saveFileDialog.CreatePrompt = true;
    saveFileDialog.FileName = null;
    saveFileDialog.Title = "Save path of the file to be exported";

    if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        Application excelObj = (Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
        Activate(); // <-- added (recommend by msdn, but maybe not nessary here)
        Workbook wbook = excelObj.ActiveWorkbook;
        wbook.SaveAs(saveFileDialog.FileName, XlFileFormat.xlExcel8, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, false, false, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        //                wbook.Close(); // <-- don't want this anymore
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can't you use the .xlsx format. Edit:  Ok I think I see now.  You are forcing it to save with a .xls extension, but you are saving it in the .xlsx format.  I suggest you change your save filter to *.xlsx

Comment: I tryed with .xlsx format combine with a stream earlier (instead of saving with the wbook) but then I could't open the file.
I'll try saveFileDialog.Filter = "Execl files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx"; combined the the wbook.SaveAs() solution now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With your code you save the workbook as Open XML because `XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault` evaluates to `XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook` for Excel 2007+. This is the reason of the warning: you named the file as XLS but actually it is a XLSX.

You can change the file extension to xlsx in your `saveFileDialog.Filter` property or force the Excel object to save in the XLS format using `XlFileFormat.xlExcel8`.

**EDIT**
Use this to save your document:

```
wbook.SaveAs(saveFileDialog.FileName, XlFileFormat.xlExcel8, 
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, false, false, 
            XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

Comment: I have tryed both changing to `saveFileDialog.Filter = "Execl files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx";` and 
and to `XlFileFormat.xlExcel8` and it still dosn't work.

Comment: I understand the first part, but I can see what more I can try. Can I ask you to update your answer, where you add my code in a edited version like your would do it?

Comment: It works - excellent answer Thank you. I'll edit my final solution to my question, for others, it have some other nice changes too.

Answer (score 2):

try to set alerts to OFF

```
oExcel.DisplayAlerts = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem results from a feature called Extension Hardening, and you can find more information about it [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsofficedeveloper/archive/2008/03/11/excel-2007-extension-warning.aspx).

Unfortunately, the link above also states that there are no expected changes to this code until at least Office 14.

If you don’t want to look for a solution, but just want to solve the problem, insert this key in your registry to suppress the notification:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Excel\Security] “ExtensionHardening”=dword:00000000
```

You can accomplish the above by doing the following:

Open your Registry (*Start* -> *Run* -> `regedit.exe`).

Navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\OFFICE\12.0\EXCEL\SECURITY`.

Right click in the right window and choose *New* -> *DWORD*

Type “`ExtensionHardening`” as the name (without the quotes)

Verify that the data has the value “`0`″.

Comment: Thanks Romil but I think I can't do this, because I don't want to set this up for all my customers.

Comment: If you are good for allowing hard coding of the extension of excel file then the approach suggested by Adriano is best for you.