# why microsoft office excel popup is coming

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, export-to-excel

i am using **GridViewExportUtil** to save my all excel in server folder path.but i don't understand why i am getting popup during open the excel.i don't want this popup.
i need to modify my code so that it will not come?.please tell me what should i do.

below is warning message if file extention is .xls

The file you are trying to open, "Myexcel.xls', is in a different format than specified by the file extension.verify that the file is not corrupted and is from a trusted source before opening the file.do you want to open the file now?.

Comment: Most of the export functionality generate the excel report using open xml programming, which do contain the different format incompersition of ms excel. that is the reason you are getting warning message while opening the exported excel sheet.

Comment: I think that's a duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10498375/how-do-i-save-an-excel-file-without-getting-a-format-warning-when-opening-using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575117/how-to-disable-popups-when-openning-in-office-interop